# cargo build-sbf no such command: `+solana`

Tags: rust, cargo, build-sbf

[image]

I have installed solana and run the command 'solana-install init 1.18.7', but still report an error,what can i do to solve the problem

Comment: Be sure to also install the latest version of Rust https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install